# Question from Liu, Chapter 5 Ex 1.16

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

I have a question from Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry, doing Chapter 5 Question 1.16:

Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a morphism of schemes, with the following base change.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_{T}:=X\times_{S}T @>{f_{T}}>> T;\\
@V{p}VV @VV{\pi}V \\
X @>{f}>>S;
\end{CD}$$

1) If $\mathcal{F}$ is an arbitrary $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module, show that we have a canonical homomorphism: $\pi^{*}f_{*}\mathcal{F}\rightarrow (f_{T})_{*}p^{*}\mathcal{F}.$

[**My attempt**] I used the adjoint property to get the following (suppressing some notations for convenience)

$$\mbox{Hom}(\pi^{*}f_{*}\mathcal{F},(f_{T})_{*}p^{*}\mathcal{F})\\
\cong \mbox{Hom}(\mathcal{F},f^{*}f_{*}p_{*}p^{*}\mathcal{F})$$

from which we can obtain a canonical homomorphism. **Question: Is this okay?**

2) Suppose that $T\rightarrow S$ is flat, and $\mathcal{F}$ quasi-coherent. If $X$ is Noetherian (or $f$ is separated and quasi-compact), show that $\pi^{*}f_{*}\mathcal{F}\rightarrow (f_{T})_{*}p^{*}\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism.

**Remark: I am stuck on this. Why do we need the condition that $X$ is Noetherian or $f$ is quasi-compact and separated??**

**Remark 2: I have no idea as well why we need flat condition.**

3) Let $X$ and $f$ as in the previous question (I am not sure what he means. I think he means we need $X$ Noetherian **and** $f$ quasi-compact and separated). Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a locally free sheaf on $S$. Show that we have the canonical isomorphism:
$$ f_{*}\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}}\mathcal{G}\cong f_{*}(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{O_{X}}f^{*}\mathcal{G})$$

[**My attempt**] I did some preliminary calculations by cheating a bit: restricting to an open set where $\mathcal{G}$ is free, we may assume that $\mathcal{G}\cong\mathcal{O}_{S}^{(I)}$ for some indexing set $I$.

On one hand we have

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&f_{*}\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}}\mathcal{G}\\
&\cong& f_{*}\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}}\mathcal{O}_{S}^{(I)}\\
&\cong& (f_{*}\mathcal{F})^{(I)}\end{eqnarray}$$

On the other

$$\begin{eqnarray} && f_{*}(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{O_{X}}f^{*}\mathcal{G})\\
&\cong& f_{*}(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{O_{X}}f^{*}O_{S}^{(I)})\\
&\cong& f_{*}(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{O_{X}}(f^{*}O_{S})^{(I)})\\
&\cong& f_{*}(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{O_{X}}\mathcal{O}_{X}^{(I)})\\
&\cong& f_{*}(\mathcal{F}^{(I)})\cong (f_{*}\mathcal{F})^{(I)}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Of course I made a lot of logical leaps, because the problem is I still have **not used the special condition! ($X$ Noetherian and $f$ quasi-compact, separated).** Where is the problem and where should I use the condition.

Appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: The assumption that $X$ is Noetherian or  $f$ quasi-compact and separated is used to guarantee that $f_\ast \mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent. Without it, it is not true that the pushforward of a quasi-coherent sheaf is quasi-coherent.

Comment: You can find the proof of Benja's assertion on Harshtorne's Chapter II Section V.